# Are Altean face markings natural or artificial?

Tags: voltron, voltron-legendary-defender

All Alteans I can remember seem to have some type of facial marking, usual some bright, almost glowing color.

Princess Allura:
[image]

Coran:
[image]

> Hagar/Honerva
>  [image]

And also King Alfor.

What I can't tell is if this is some sort of biological marking they all have, or some traditional makeup or tattoo. The examples I can recall are all members of high or noble class. I don't know if all Alteans have it, from lack of examples.

Comment: Any use to you? http://galrakeithiscanon.tumblr.com/post/157375264538/so-i-noticed-something-in-the-scenes-where-the

Comment: @Valorum Tumblr is never really of use to me.

Comment: @CreationEdge S5E6 answers this definitively. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Machavity I'll read the update once I've finished the season, then.

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be biological. In S2E1, the Castle gets stuck in a wormhole void loop where Coran keeps getting younger and younger, until he is a baby. Each iteration keeps the markings

[image]

[image]

Something interesting is

> Honerva's become distorted after years of studying the Quintessence. It's unclear why
> [image]
>  Until they finally sag down her face
>  [image]

Season 5, Episode 6 finally answers this definitively, that they are biological

> Upon reaching a location where Lotor theorizes Altean alchemy originated, both he and Allura have their marks begin to glow (Lotor's are not normally visible because he is half Galra). Coran's do not glow because Lotor states that only the chosen have theirs glow. [image]

Comment: Why wouldn't the makeup stay on his face if he was de-aging?

Comment: @Valorum The markings change with the size, tho. It's not conclusive, but there's nothing canon to suggest it's makeup. I wouldn't expect a baby to have makeup

Comment: In Western human society, make up on young children is abnormal outside of pageants and photography. But, I'm not sure about Altean society. I was thinking about this episode when I wrote the question, but didn't find it conclusive. The change to Honerva's actually make me think it's _less_ a "natural" marking, and more some sort of biological response to quintessence exposure that they all seem to have to some degreev

Comment: Is there any way to reconcile the last part of this answer with the series' finale?

Comment: @Will I think what happened to Keith was due solely to Allura. It would make for an interesting question